# how to generate data and how to pass it over?

Tags: c++

let's say that i need to create some buffer or a vector of objects or whatever

and that data needs to be given to an object constructor...

is it common practice to be generate the data in a class function like this

```
class A
{
    void gen()
    {
        vector<Data*> v;
        obj= new Obj(&v);
    }
}
```

...

```
class Obj
{
private:
    vector<Data*> *data;
public:
    Obj(vector<Data*> *v)
    {
        data=v;
    }
}
```

good idea? bad idea?

the background question would be do i use pointers, references... as entry and output of my functions & constructors, when and for what reason...

thanks

Comment: Read [this about RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), it could be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In particular, this is a *very* bad idea:

```
{
    vector<Data*> v;
    obj= new Obj(&v); // 1: pass address of v
}                     // 2: v gets destroyed (obj will hold the address of
                      //    an out-of-scope variable) and application will
                      //    probably crash when it attempts to use it.
```

> do i use pointers, references... as entry and output of my functions & constructors, when and for what reason...

That's a ... broad subject. In general, you should:

- use objects directly, when declaring them in a scope (by value).
- pass objects by const reference, when the function you pass them in just needs read-only access.
- pass objects by non-const reference when the function alters the object
- if you need an object outside of the scope you create it in, return by value if possible, otherwise use a pointer (see "avoiding raw pointers" below)

Avoiding raw pointers:

- raw pointers (T*) should be:

  - replaced with std::unique_ptr when only one owner of the pointer will exists (when the pointer is used in one place)
  - replaced with std::shared_ptr when ownership is shared, there are multiple owners, or when there is no clear owner of the pointer.
  - replaced with std::vector when you need an arbitrary length array of values
  - replaced with std::array when you need an array of n values
  - the only places where you use raw pointers are:
  - when you are interested in the pointer values themselves (e.g. logging allocated addresses, tracking memory, writing an allocator or object pool, implementing an iterator type)
  - when you are interacting with legacy or the C library.

In your particular case:

```
class Obj
{
private:
    vector<Data*> data; // store by value
public:
    Obj(vector<Data*> v) // pass by value (creates a copy of the data)
    : data{ std::move(v) } // move passed value into internal member
    {
    } 
};

class A
{
    Obj gen()                     // return obj by value
    {
        vector<Data*> v;          // allocate by value
        Obj obj{ std::move(v) };  // move v into obj
        return obj;               // return by value
    }
};
```